# First page style change the footer of other pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm writing a class file. In this class, I'm trying to define a style for the first page, and another one for the other pages. The style for the first page is:

```
\fancypagestyle{MECStitlepagestyle}{%
  \lhead{
    {\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\textbf{
    \protect\MECSname, \@MECSissueYear, 1-\@MECSarticlePages}}\\
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont 
    Published Online January \@MECSissueYear~in MECS (\MECSwebsite}\\
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont DOI: \@MECSarticleDOI}
  }
  \rhead{
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm, width=2.54cm]{logo}
  }
  \lfoot{
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont 
        Copyright \copyright~\@MECSissueYear~MECS}
  }
  \rfoot{
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\textit{
        \protect\MECSname, \@MECSissueYear, 1-\@MECSarticlePages}}
  }
  \chead{}
}

\def\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
  \def\thefootnote{} % the \thanks{} mark type is empty
  \if@tmptwocolumn
    \twocolumn[\@maketitle]
  \else
    \@maketitle
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{MECStitlepagestyle}
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}\let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax
  \gdef\@thanks{}\gdef\@author{}\gdef\@title{}\let\thanks\relax
}

\def\@maketitle{\newpage
  \begin{center}
    \vskip4.0em{\fontsize{24pt}{28pt}\selectfont\@title\par}\vskip1.0em%
    {\lineskip.5em\large\@author\par}
  \end{center}\par\vskip 1.4em
}
```

The style for the other ones is:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont 
        Copyright \copyright~\@MECSissueYear~MECS}
}
\rfoot{
    {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\textit{
        \protect\MECSname, \@MECSissueYear, 1-\@MECSarticlePages}}    
}
\cfoot{}

\fancyhead[CE, CO]{{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\MECSarticleTitle}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

\def\sectionmark#1{\relax}
```

The first page style works ok. But this style change de footer size of the other pages. I don't understand why this happens, neither how can I fix it. Could someone help me?

Comment: Wluld you mind posting a compilable ecample that reproduces the behaviour instead of posting mere snippets?

Comment: Participação brasileira

Comment: \AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{MECStitlepagestyle}} should do the trick.